# Embedded tweet in HTML dreamweaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I would like to embed a tweet into my website.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="en" data-theme="dark" href="https://twitter.com/russdiemon">Tweets by russdiemon</a> 
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"> </script>
```

That's the code twitter tells me to insert but all it does is make a hyperlink. I want a live feed on my website.

Comment: <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="en" data-theme="dark" href="https://twitter.com/russdiemon">Tweets by russdiemon</a> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"> </script>                        That's the code I would like to embed

Answer (score 0):

The below is working for me. https://jsfiddle.net/o9yfwdke/1/

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="en" data-theme="dark" href="https://twitter.com/russdiemon">Tweets by russdiemon</a> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```